# geom_smooth(method=loess) is not working - argument trace.hat is missing

Tags: r, ggplot2, loess

I made this code in the spring and for some reason it is not working anymore and R doesn't draw the plots. When I try to use grid.arrange to draw them, I get the following warning message:

Warning messages:
1: Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
argument "trace.hat" is missing, with no default

Here's a piece of the code that used to work flawlessly:

```
sc.occpt.ptre<-ggplot(subset(sc, species %in% c("Ptre")), aes(x=sizeclass, y=occpt)) +
 geom_smooth(method=loess, color="black", size=0.5)+
 coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,2.5))+
 theme_pub2()+
 theme(axis.title.y = element_blank())+
 theme(axis.title.x = element_blank())+
 scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(10, 45, by = 5))+
 annotate("text",-Inf,Inf,hjust=0,vjust=2,label="Populus tremula",family="sans", size=1.7)+
 annotate("text",-Inf,Inf,hjust=-0.07,vjust=4,label="Spearman's rho = 0.25, p = 0.007", family="sans",fontface="italic", size=1.7)
```

and I use this code to draw the plots:

```
grid.arrange(sc.occpt.ptre, sc.occpt.bsp, sc.occpt.blt, sc.occpt.pabi, sc.occpt.psyl, sc.occpt.all, ncol=2, left = textGrob("Occurrences per CWD item", rot=90))
```

I can't figure out how I should put the argument trace.hat in my code nor why I suddenly need it in the first place. Thank you in advance!

head(sc). Sizeclass and occpt are both numeric.

```
          h       sppt     occpt countl sizeclass sites2   sites     x_co    y_co spc   area reg freg no type species decay dia empty
1 0.6931472 0.66666667 0.6666667      3        10   AIMA AIMALA1 350855.3 6799399   2 0.4521  EH   2a  1    2     Blt     2  11     0
2 0.4505612 0.25000000 0.7500000      8        10   AIMA AIMALA2 350408.1 6800231   2 0.9955  EH   2a  1    3     Blt     3  12     0
3 0.6365142 0.33333333 0.5000000      6        10   AIMA AIMALA3 350478.3 6799771   2 0.5283  EH   2a  5    3     Blt     2  12     0
4 1.0549202 0.37500000 0.6250000      8        10   AIMA AIMALA4 350480.3 6799868   3 0.7139  EH   2a  6    3     Blt     1  11     0
5 1.0114043 0.10000000 0.2000000     30        10   HAIL HAILUO1 395750.1 7219345   3 0.2405  OP   3a  7    8     Blt     5  10     1
6 1.0889000 0.08888889 0.2222222     45        10   HAIL HAILUO2 387392.3 7217148   4 0.1562  OP   3a  6    8     Blt     4  12     1
```

Comment: What version of R are you using? Have you changed it since you first wrote the code?

Comment: Yes, I'm using R on different computer now, so the version might be different. The one in this computer seems to be R 3.0.1. Maybe I will give this code a try on my own computer that still has the same version of R what I used in the spring (but right now I cant remember what version it is).

Comment: Bleh, it is not working on my computer either...

Comment: I reinstalled both R and Rstudio to their latest versions, I still get the warning of argument trace.hat

Comment: Please post `head(sc)`

Comment: This is strange. `trace.hat` should be provided automatically by `loess.control`, with the default value `c("exact","approximate")`.

Comment: I'll add head(sc) to my original question, as requested.

Comment: @James , I know right! I'm so frustated about this, I don't get how I should try to solve this. I tried setting trace.hat manually by

    `loess.control(trace.hat="exact")`

and checked it by inputting loess.control(), got this as output, so I suppose the trace.hat should be set?

    `$trace.hat
 [1] "exact"`

Comment: Does `match.fun("loess")` return the correct function? i.e the one from `stats`

Comment: @James I gave that command and it gave me this:

`function (formula, data, weights, subset, na.action, model = FALSE, 
    span = 0.75, enp.target, degree = 2L, parametric = FALSE, 
    drop.square = FALSE, normalize = TRUE, family = c("gaussian", 
        "symmetric"), method = c("loess", "model.frame"), control = loess.control(...), 
    ...) 
{'
`
the function continues further and has also this line:


`if (!is.list(control) || !is.character(control$surface) || 
        !is.character(control$statistics) || !is.character(control$trace.hat)`

Comment: ... but I have no idea how to check if it is the right function.

Also, I tried method=lm and it worked great, so I suppose you're on the right path and it indeed is the loess function itself that is not working.